# Borderless tabular (array, grid) structure with Rmarkdown

Tags: r, latex, knitr, r-markdown, pandoc

Is there any way I can achieve a gridless tabular (array) structure with Rmarkdown. I have to get the same gridless structure in PDF and HTML. I am using Rmarkdown, Bookdown and Blogdown. I tried with `knitr::kable` and some functions with `pander` package. For example:

```
my.data <- matrix(c(2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9), nrow = 3, ncol = 2)
rownames(my.data) <- LETTERS[1:3]
knitr::kable(my.data)
pander::pander(my.data)
```

In both the cases, the PDF version of the table is not gridless, instead it has top and bottom horizontal line. Is there any what to get this completely bordless.

Answer (score 1):

A solution not using one of the mentioned pacakges, but `gridExtra` is this:

```
library(gridExtra)
grid.arrange(
   tableGrob(my.data, theme = ttheme_minimal()))
```

This gives a table with no boarders in HTML and Latex. Another advantage is the possibility to customize the `ttheme_minimal` theme, see [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gridExtra/vignettes/tableGrob.html#aesthetic-formatting).

Answer (score 0):

You may also try

```
library(pixiedust)
dust(my.data)
```

If your HTML document has CSS applied to the tables, it will be applied to the `dust` object as well (such as in a vignette). Otherwise, it will be plain.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility:

```
library(huxtable)
as_hux(my.data)
```